# How do I solve this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y^{(7)}+4y^{(6)}+8y^{(5)}+9y^{(4)}+8y^{(3)}+8y^{(2)}+8y^{(1)}+4y=e^{-x} (5sinx-cosx) $

The characteristic equation $ \lambda ^7 +4\lambda ^6+8\lambda ^5+ 9\lambda ^4 +8\lambda ^3+8\lambda ^2+8\lambda +4= (\lambda ^2 +2\lambda +2)^2(\lambda ^3+1) $  has equal roots $\lambda _1=\lambda _2= i-1 ; \lambda _3=\lambda_4=-i-1 ; \lambda_5 =-1 ; \lambda_6= \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt 3}{2}  ; \lambda _7= \frac{1}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt 3}{2} $

Hence, I can write solution of the homogeneous equation.

Then , because $\lambda_1 $ and  are $\lambda_3 $ double roots $e^{-x} (5sinx-cosx) $ ,

I'm looking for  solutions form : $ y^{**}(t)=t^2(a \cos t+b \sin t)$

Does anybody can do it faster than expected $7$ derivative $y^{**}(t)$ ?

Comment: I tried to count also on the complex, but it did'nt work.

Comment: Are you looking for the general solution or a particular one?

Comment: I'm looking for a particular integrals

Comment: @Amzoti: It was typo, but you're right

Comment: A faster way? Mathematica/Maple would be fast, but I see what you mean. You'll get patterns, lots of cancellations in the derivatives - you probably could have done it by now - in general for algebra that's too long/messy a CAS is the best way to go. I'll be interested to hear if there are any 'clever' ways though.

Comment: Ok, but  wolfram doesn't caculate.
I wanted to find  complex solution : $At^2e^{(i-1)t}$,but when I assigned derivatives and I put into the equation, I gained a contradiction

Comment: Can someone please help me find the integral of a special or point me to where I make mistake?